# How many characters can i print using System.out.println in java

Tags: java, char, ascii

i wonder, how many characters can i print using standard output in java on `windows`
Like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++){
   System.out.println((char)i);
}
```

What ascii table using standard output?

Comment: Java's default `file.encoding` on Windows is `Cp1252` but you can change it. That encoding supports the ASCII chars (0-0x7F), slightly less than 32 Windows-chosen characters mostly in the U+20xx block, and the "G1" part of ISO-8859-1 aka Latin-1 (0xA0-0xFF). Other 8-bit encodings will provide 256 or slightly less characters but different ones. Unicode encodings will provide  the nearly 65536 "UCS-2" or "BMP" chars, and optionally more; the UTF-8 and UTF-16{,BE,LE}[BOM] encodings are supported by many/most other software on Windows but not all; UTF-8 is supported by many other systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. You can go upto 255. After 255 all you can see for (char)i is ?

```
public class Testing{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        for(int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++){
            System.out.println(i+" "+(char)i);
            if(i == 270){
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your text, you use '255', but in your code you use '270'. Explanation ?

Comment: Just to show that 15 lines will print ? `After 255 all you can see for (char)i is ?`

Answer (score 0):

Since a `String` is a `char-array` you should be limited by the `Integer.MAX_VALUE(2147483647)`. Although most of the IDE's have a custom limit for the console output.

Comment: Java `char` is 16 bits unsigned and limited to 65535, and the values are the characters in the Unicode "Basic Multilingual Plane" (BMP). Some additional (but rare) *characters* are represented by *two* `char`s, called a "surrogate pair". Casting `int` to `char` takes the low 16 bits, so that loop repeats all `chars` a hair less than 32768 times.

Answer (score 0):

your code does not concatenate or accumulate output so it will print 1 char at a time
so it will print 2^31-1 (2 to the power 31) - 1 character each in a separate line

though, some characters will appear as rubbish character or a white space, this is due to the charset being used, and supported by the IDE/terminal view used to display the output.

more on [Integer.MAX_VALUE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE)